# reading separate lines of data in a grid using c#

Tags: c#, .net

Given a data text file which looks like

- 21,7,11
- 20,10,12
- 17,7,18

These represent height, temperature and carbon percentage.

I have read in the file as a .txt file using system.io. Is this correct? from here how would I calculate the maximum temperature?

```
 {
        string s;
        System.IO.StreamReader inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(DataFile);
        s = inputFile.ReadLine();
        int noDataLines = int.Parse(s);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "is this correct"? Is what correct? And where's your attempt at reading all the lines and determining the max temp?

Comment: No, it is not correct. You are trying to read a line and then parse entire line to int with commas in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all the lines and compare each value to find out max temperature.
Something like below (untested code!) should be done. There are lot of assumptions in this code and you may have to change it to suit your case.

```
{    
    string s;
    int maxValue=-1, temp=-1;
    using(System.IO.StreamReader in = new System.IO.StreamReader(DataFile))
    {
        while (in.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            s = in.ReadLine();
            if(int.tryParse(s.split(",")[1], out temp)
            {
                if(temp>maxValue)
                   maxValue = temp;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to create a two-dimensional list or array, and in this example I am using a list.

```
{
    List<List<int>> intList = new List<int>(); // This creates a two dimensional list.
    System.IO.StreamReader inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(DataFile);
    string line = inputFile:ReadLine();
    while (line != null) // Iterate over the lines in the document.
    {
        intList.Add( // Adding a new row to the list.
            line.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList()
            // This separates the line by commas, and turns it into a list of integers.
        );
        line = inputFile:ReadLine(); // Move to the next row.
    }
}
```

I will admit that this is certainly not a very concise method of doing it, but it is relatively straightforward.

To access it, do this:

```
int element = intList[1, 2]; // Accessing 2nd row, 3rd column.
```